# Wrong battery percentage when using ubuntu

Tags: power-management, battery, indicator

I am using Ubuntu 21.04 dual boot with windows 10. When I use Ubuntu the battery percentage which is shown is not consistent. sometimes when I connect the charge, I hear the sound that comes from my pc when charging but the charging symbol does not show up near the battery icon. Also when using ubuntu the battey drains very quickly and sometimes even charges up very quickly which I find abnormal as it does not happen when I use windows. Pl. help ASAP as I am a new user.
Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

Install TLP - this has many features to maximize battery life. Could also be that there is some program sapping the battery power. Is the fans on and running at hi speed all the time? I have heard that not having the correct video drivers can have that effect. Could it be the battery age? Is it a genuine one for your laptop or aftermarket? I have had no issues with my battery running 20.04... Lasts 3-4 days in standby, 5 hours during active use, but I think that's not bad...

```
sudo apt install tlp
```

for one. I also recommend you run the laptop completely down to a powered down state. Then charge to full, i would do this twice